# Create zipfile with directory entries in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3

For a unit test, I need a zipfile that contains directory entries. In a pinch, I could create one manually and keep it in the repo in binary form, but I'd rather create it dynamically as part of the test setup.

Neither the `zipfile` module nor `shutil.make_archive` seems to be able to create directory entries. Is there a native-python solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instinctively I would go with your approach "keep it in the repor in binary form", especially since it would be quite small and guaranteed to be identical across platforms.

For dynamically creating such a ZIP file, you probably need to go the "long way" to first the target structure on disc. For that, I would be using [os.makedirs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=makedirs#os.makedirs) within a [tempfile.TemporaryDirectory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryDirectory), then compressing it.

Comment: I actually already have the target structure, which is used for other tests. I just also need to run tests on a zipped version of that structure that has directory entries.

Comment: That's strange: `os.makedirs('test/folder/structure')` followed by `shutil.make_archive('test', format='zip', base_dir='test')` works fine (i.e. file test.zip contains the nested directory structure when viewed with any viewer). What does not work as expected?

Comment: I read the archive using zipinfo and I didn't see any directory entries in there. Maybe I missed something. I'll check again.

Comment: You're right. I tried it before, but I must have been doing something wrong.